# Magento 1.9.x show, value cart rules in products page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to show the value of the discount created with the cart rules, and applied to the products set in the rule with sku.

The first idea, I came to mind was to create a dropdown attribute and then call it on the product page, and it works. But this creates me the difficulty, I have to set this attribute for thousands of products.

So, I would like to find a solution that would allow me to see the value of the discount applied to the cart rule or Label and in alternative description of the cart rule, for the various sku for which the rule is set.

Do you have any suggestions how make it?

Thanks